# Read Only file system error

Tags: files, filesystem, ext4, read-only

My system often goes into Read-Only mode.
System details:

```
Linux amrav 3.19.0-78-generic #86~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 6 17:58:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of some of the commands which I tried from other answers on stackoverflow.

```
$ dmesg | grep "error"
[   25.457633] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   27.346559] [drm:intel_uncore_check_errors [i915]] *ERROR* Unclaimed register before interrupt
```

I even get the following error while trying to access (copy a file) from a certain directory in the hard disk:

```
There was an error copying the file into /home/amrav.
Error opening file '/home/amrav/train_iter_.txt': Read-only file system
```

And whenever I start the terminal, I get the following error:

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system
Could not create temporary file: 
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system
Could not create temporary file: 
zsh: locking failed for /home/amrav/.zsh_history: read-only file system: reading anyway
```

Comment: Most likely your hard drive is failing. Back up any and all data you value NOW. You can run smartmontools and fsck to investigate - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: But I'm unable to copy any data that I find to be useful from my harddisk. I get the error. Do you mean to backup the data from a live boot session ?

Comment: Yes back up your data to an external device such as a flash drive or CD/DVD ASAP. I would boot live system. If you can not read the data at all you may be looking at data recovery.